# Powershell shortcut on desktop: Chain two commands

Tags: powershell, command, chain

I'm trying to create a shortcut on the desktop:

```
%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -command import-module \\fs\PS\MyModule\MyModule.dll
```

That is working. Furthermore I want to read all commands of that module, after opening PS automatically. How do I append the following:

```
get-commands -Module MyModule
```

Thx
piccus

Comment: Why don't you simply put the two statements in your [profile](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try somesthing like this

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command "& { import-module \\fs\PS\MyModule\MyModule.dll; ... others command ...}"
```